# what is the zero connected to some MUX in this 8 bit right shifter

Tags: cpu, bit, bit-shift, processor, shift

[image]

in this picture of an 8 bit right shifter, can someone please tell me what those 0's represent ? in the first row of MUX there is one zero connect, in the second row the first two have 0 connected, and in the third row there are 4 zeros connected?

Answer (score 2):

There are three shifting possibilities:

- *shift(0)* is the bit0 of the shift amount. It weights 2<sup>0</sup> = 1.
  Setting that bit shift *at least* 1 bit.
- *shift(1)* is the bit1 of the shift amount. It weights 2<sup>1</sup> = 2.
  Setting that bit shift *at least* 2 bits.
- *shift(2)* is the bit2 of the shift amount. It weights 2<sup>2</sup> = 4.
  Setting that bit shift *at least* 4 bits.

When shifting the incoming bits must be set to zero for logical shifts ( `01001101` shifted left by 3 becomes `01101000`) and that's the reason for those zeros.

The circuit (a [barrel shifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter)) basically decomposes a shift amount into a sum of powers of two (e.g. 5 as 1 + 4) so that any amount in the range 0-7 (3-bit of a number) can be done using a fixed arrangement of wires in one clock.
A SISO (Serial In, Serial Out) register would require multiple clock cycles.